# NSIS Scroll License Plugin

Tags: nsis

Does anyone have experience with the NSIS Scroll License Plugin?

I am trying to get the scroll license plugin to force a scroll to the end of a EULA. I have the following lines of code included (see below); the problem I am running into is the Welcome Screen has the next button greyed out so I cant even get to the license page with this plugin :( Any ideas on this one?

Thanks much!

## Defines

```
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW LicenseShow
```

## INSERTMACROS

```
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE mylicense.txt
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English
```

Section -Main SEC0000
   Lots of files
SectionEnd

## Functions

```
LicenseForceSelection checkbox

Function LicenseShow
  ScrollLicense::Set /NOUNLOAD
FunctionEnd

Function .onGUIEnd
  ScrollLicense::Unload
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: You did not provided a [Short Self Contained Correct Example](http://sscce.org)... It is missing a number of statements like the include of MUI.nsh

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a number of things in the code you provided to let us test your code. Note also that you need at least one section.

Here is a minimal running sample :

```
!include "MUI.nsh"

Name    "ScrollLicense Test"
OutFile "ScrollLicense.exe" 

!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW LicenseShow
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE mylicense.txt

!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English

LicenseForceSelection checkbox

Function LicenseShow
  ScrollLicense::Set /NOUNLOAD
FunctionEnd

Function .onGUIEnd
  ScrollLicense::Unload
FunctionEnd

Section "A Section"
;some things to install
;...
SectionEnd
```

Comment: My code works perfectly fine until I include this string....  Function LicenseShow
  ScrollLicense::Set /NOUNLOAD
FunctionEnd

Comment: @user1304228: Then you should have copy / paste that working code instead of that non-working stripped version. Do you have any warning / message in the NSIS compilation log ?

Comment: No it will compile just fine, but the Welcome screen Next button will be greyed out

Comment: Anyone have any clues on this one?